# Playing Audio in a thread? java

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I have a thread that is used to animate a JPanel. I also want some audio to play the duration of the animation and then stop when the animation stops. Essentially I want to sync the audio with the animation. I've tried something like this but nothing works. I've also tried playing the audio outside of the while statement. The while statement does eventually end when I return based on some case.

```
public void run() 
        {
         Clip clip=null;
                try
                {
                    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(ImageIcon);
                    clip.start();
                    System.out.println("playing sound?");
                } 
                catch (LineUnavailableException e1)
                {
                   System.out.println("something wrong with adio");
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("something wrong with adio");
                }

            while(true)
            {
                //animation stuff

                try
                {sleep(150);} 
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"nothing works"* What's the problem? What happens?

Comment: I realized that I have to start the clip outside the while loop but for some reason if I start the clip a second time no audio plays

Comment: If you know you need to start the Clip outside the loop, can you show that code then? Please show the code that you think should work. And what is `BattleShip.this.Explode`? Consider editing your question to include a [minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where did you get your sound from ? `clip.open(ImageIcon)` seems strange to me. If you want to sync something, you should use `clip.getMicrosecondPosition()`.